# How can I shoot while hiding in Red Dead Redemption on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, red-dead-redemption

Towards the beginning of Red Dead Redemption, there is a tutorial where John Marston helps the sheriff to attack a gang.

During the tutorial, you are shown how to hide behind a rock and shoot by holding the gun above the rock.

I've not been able to do it since - can anyone tell me the controls?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just hit RB (Right Bumper) when you get to the object you want to cover behind... Is that not working for you?

Comment: I hadn't tried that - problem was I had forgotten the controls to use :) Will try that later today and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Press RB you'll go into cover. Then just aim and shoot normally LT for aim (he'll go out of cover to look for targets) and RT to shoot.

Comment: Alternativley you can just press shoot and the character will shoot blindly towards where you are viewing. Shooting from cover really. As opposed to aiming first.